# How can I get command stdout from a process using assert_cli crate?

Tags: rust, integration-testing

I am using [assert_cli](https://docs.rs/assert_cli/0.5.4/assert_cli/) crate to test a command line application. While it is very helpful with simple use cases ([see some examples in this article](https://mattgathu.github.io/testing-rust-cli-apps/)), sometimes I want to get the raw output of the command I am testing as a `String` to do more sophisticated checks (regex, json or just more complex logic in the output).

For that I need to get a copy of the command output verbatim. Here is an example:

```
extern crate assert_cli;

fn main() {
    let a = assert_cli::Assert::command(&["echo", "foo-bar-foo"]);
    a.execute();
    println!("{:?}", a.expect_output);
}
```

Somewhat predictably it gives me the following error:

```
error[E0616]: field `expect_output` of struct `assert_cli::Assert` is private
  --> src/main.rs:14:22
   |
14 |     println!("{:?}", a.expect_output);
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It also has a `.stdout()` method, but that requires [OutputAssertionBuilder](https://docs.rs/assert_cli/0.5.4/assert_cli/struct.OutputAssertionBuilder.html) and there it is also not obvious how to access the *actual contents* of `stdout`. You can only do some simple checks using predicates syntax.

`assert_cli` does internally get the full output of the command during execute as seen in the source code of [assert.rs](https://docs.rs/assert_cli/0.5.4/src/assert_cli/assert.rs.html#320)

```
let output = spawned.wait_with_output()?;
```

All the internal `Command` and `output` variables seem to be private and are never exposed to retrieve the raw `stdout`. This functionality seems to be too basic to be omitted from `assert_cli` library. I am probably missing something very obvious...

Q: Is there any way to get raw `stdout` back as contents of a variable?

This is what I want to achieve ideally:

```
extern crate assert_cli;

fn main() {
    // do simple checkign with assert_cli
    let a = assert_cli::Assert::command(&["echo", "foo-bar-foo"])
        .stdout().contains("foo-bar-foo")
        .unwrap();

    // get raw stdout
    let cmd_stdout = a.get_raw_stdout(); // how to do it?

    // do some additional complex checking
    assert_eq!(cmd_stdout, "foo-bar-foo");
}
```

P.S.: I know I can use [std::process::Command](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) separately to achieve this. I wonder if I can still stick to `assert_cli` since I do 80% of the testing with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library defines only 3 types. None of which allow to access the output directly.

> This functionality seems to be too basic to be omitted from `assert_cli` library. I am probably missing something very obvious...

The library is called `assert*` and it has all the functions you need to assert stuffs on the output of your command. Getting the actual output is outside the domain of "assertions".

Other people have opened [an issue](https://github.com/assert-rs/assert_cli/issues/94) on the repository asking for this exact feature. I suggest you to go there, and tell the author that this feature interests you.

Comment: Thank you, somehow I missed that one in the bug tracker... I do agree with the premise that assertion library should kind of not do that, but at the same time the assertion library doesn't provide enough flexibility to achieve all types of checks. Running the same process for the second time just to check different part of the output seems wasteful. There is also process management plumbing in place that I'd like to not copy/paste into my code. I think there should be this feature, if not for elegance, then for efficiency sake.